# how to replace all the ? and = by / htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello all i have a site in which i would like to replace all the ? and = of urls by / .
i know this cn be done by htaccess file but i am very new to htaccess

i have this code in my htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
 Options -Indexes 
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page1)\.php\?eid=(78)[&\s] [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(page1)/(\d+)$ /$1.php?eid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page2\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
     RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page2.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

thnkx in advance ...
i wana replace all the ? and = of the url by /
like

```
    domain.com/page.php?id=44 by 
    domain.com/page/id/4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to clarify what you intend to accomplish.

If you intend to have the user visit domain.com/page/id/4 and have it internally be rewritten to page.php?id=4, then you have two options:

1) use a rewrite rule, such as:

RewriteRule ^/?page/([^/]+)/(.+)$ page.php?$1=$2
2) (preferred) use MultiViews and have your php script do the logic for you by parsing the

REQUEST_URI ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to clarify what you intend to accomplish.

If you intend to have the user visit `domain.com/page/id/4` and have it internally be rewritten to `page.php?id=4`, then you have two options:

1) use a rewrite rule, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page/([^/]+)/(.+)$ page.php?$1=$2
```

2) (preferred) use [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) and have your php script do the logic for you by parsing the

```
REQUEST_URI ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).
```